# Does github rate limit for ip if I make requests with access tokens?

Tags: api, github

I read they rate limit unauthenticated requests at 60/hour and authenticated tokens at 5k/hour. I was wondering if there's a global rate limit based on ip address, i.e. this ip can only make x requests/hour with y tokens?

Thanks.

Comment: you can check your rate limit on the api, see this: http://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: There shouldn't be such a limit i.e. there are only the 60/h and 5k/h limits. If you do hit something like a global IP limit - contact their support team to figure out what's going on (support@github.com).

Comment: @phoet The question I asked isn't addressed in that link, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least start to check that by using the [new information introduced 2d July 2013](http://developer.github.com/changes/2013-07-02-rate-limit-reset/): make queries using access token and see how the [rate limit](http://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) reset time is affected.

> That information is now available in the **new `X-RateLimit-Reset` response header**.

```
$ curl -I https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 42
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1372700873
...
```

> The X-RateLimit-Reset header provides a [Unix UTC timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), letting you know the exact time that your fresh new rate limit kicks in.
>
> The reset timestamp is also available as **part of the `/rate_limit` resource**.

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/rate_limit

{
  "rate": {
    "limit": 60,
    "remaining": 42,
    "reset": 1372700873
  }
}
```